# LDAP connection behaving weirdly over SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I am trying to connect to my organization's LDAP server using JAVA. I'm using the following code of SSLPoke to test the connection.

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;

/** Establish a SSL connection to a host and port, writes a byte and
 * prints the response. See
 * http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Connecting+to+SSL+services
 */
public class SSLPoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: "+SSLPoke.class.getName()+" <host> <port>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

            InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

            // Write a test byte to get a reaction :)
            out.write(1);

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                System.out.print(in.read());
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully connected");

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I imported the LDAP's certificate in my truststore. I am able to connect sometimes, while in majority of the cases I get -

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.securi
ty.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certifica
tion path to requested target
```

I tried running the code with SSL debug enabled but I'm unable to identify what's wrong. Had it been a certificate issue, it wouldn't have connected at all. But I'm able to connect sometimes after subsequent tries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm,... do you invoke your program with an IP or a hostname? Maybe there's N ldap servers and the DNS has a round robin functionality active for that domain and the different ldap servers have a different setup.

Comment: I invoke the program with a hostname. I doubt that is the issue.